# How can I change the background-color of a jqm slider independent from the header (Live code included)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I was searching for a solution to change the background-color for my jqm range slider.

As I've found that via the chrome developer tools, I tried to change it, but the following code is changing the Header and the slider background:

```
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-bar-inherit {
     background-color: #579e81!important;
 }
```

Is there any solution to exclude the Header from this code? I've tried it this way too, but it's not working :

```
 .sliderr .ui-page-theme-a .ui-bar-inherit {
     background-color: #579e81!important;
 }
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9yqv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the class .sliderr is assigned to an input type element, not the container for the slider itself.

Remove the .sliderr class and add another parent:

```
#content .ui-slider .ui-slider-track.ui-bar-inherit {
  background-color: #579e81 !important;
}
```